# *ngFor iterates of an observable. Filtering onInput should be possible. How?

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, observable

A view lists entries using a *ngFor based on an Observable:

**view.html**

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="filter" (ionInput)="filterMeds()"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let medicine of getMeds$() | async">
      {{medicine.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The component just relays an observable via the getMeds$() function:

**component.ts**

```
private _refreshOnInput$: Subject<any> = new Subject();


getMeds$(){
  return this.medsService.medsArray$;
}
```

The service itself just returns the array as an observable: `Observable<Medicine[]>`

Medicine is a plain object made of a few strings an numbers.

Now, my question: view.html adds a searchbar. Whenever the users modifies the search criteria, the `filterMeds()` function is called:

```
filterMeds(){
  this._refreshOnInput$.next(true);
}
```

This following a [blog post](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) (cmd-f the text "refresh button" to see what I'm trying to implement).

I understand my *ngFor must iterate on an observable that merges both the original `this.medsService.medsArray$` and the `_refreshOnInput()` after applying some filtering.

** component.ts attempt **

```
filteredMeds$: Observable<Medicine[]>

// Constructor

// An event is fired whenever the search input's updated
filteredMeds$ = this._refreshOnInput$.map( () =>
  this.medsService.medsArray$
    .map(meds =>
      meds.filter(med =>
        med.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) > -1
      )
    )
);

this.meds$ = Observable.merge(this.medsService.medsArray$, filteredMeds$);

// Updating the getMeds$() method:
getMeds$(){
  return this.medsService.medsArray$;
}
```

I can't figure out how to create a valid filtered stream. The same error happens when I directly serve the filteredMeds$ observable to *ngFor:

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not the best solution BUT it works. So, please comment on this approach:

```
  private _refreshMeds: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  meds$: Observable<any>;
  filter: string = '';

  constructor(@Inject(MedsService) private medsService: MedsService) {

    let filtered$ = new Observable( obs => {
      this._refreshMeds.subscribe( () =>
        this.medsService.medsArray$.first().subscribe( medsArray => {

          const filteredMeds = medsArray.filter(med =>
            (this.filter.length === 0 ) ||
            (med.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) > -1));
          obs.next(filteredMeds);
        })
      )
    });

    // Merging both the unfiltered (ie. at page load) or the filtered version
    this.meds$ = Observable.merge(this.medsService.medsArray$, filtered$);
  }

  // Called by the input's changed listener (ionic: ionInput)
  filterMeds(){
    this._refreshMeds.next(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you should iterate by `(getMeds$() | async)` in this way:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let medicine of (getMeds$() | async)">
```

because in your example, you are using async pipe on *medicine* object, no result of *getMeds$* method.

---

But better way is use **public** reference to medsService (in component) and your ngFor loop should looks like that:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let medicine of (medsService.medsArray$ | async)">
```

because you shouldn't use method in html (as a argument of ngFor loop or ngIf condition). Every change in view will be called getMeds$() method in your case, which is completely unnecessary for Observables.

Comment: Hi Jaroslaw, thanks for the input but I forgot to mention that the basic unfiltered observable displays properly. The issue comes from my filtering. But thanks for the best practice tip!